# Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous classes are not static/ диалоговое окно

Tags: android

Я разрабатываю приложение наподобие мобильного гардероба, и у меня есть в toolbar-е 2 кнопки редактировать и удалить. При нажатии на кнопку удалить должно выходить диалоговое окно но на этом программа зависает. AS показывает что ошибка на сходится в строке "private final DialogFragment confirmDelete =new DialogFragment()" Прилагаю код:

```
package com.example.garderob.Clothes.test;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.garderob.Clothes.broshi;
import com.example.garderob.Clothes.test.data.DatabaseDescription.Contact;
import com.example.garderob.R;

import java.util.Objects;

public class DetailFragment extends Fragment
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {


    public interface DetailFragmentListener {
        void onContactDeleted();

        void onEditContact(Uri contactUri);
    }

    private static final int CONTACT_LOADER = 0;

    private DetailFragmentListener listener;
    private Uri contactUri;

    private TextView nameTextView;
    private TextView emailTextView;


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        listener = (DetailFragmentListener) context;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        listener = null;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        Bundle arguments = getArguments();

        if (arguments != null)
            contactUri = arguments.getParcelable(broshi.CONTACT_URI);


        View view =
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);


        nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        emailTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descript);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(CONTACT_LOADER, null, this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_details_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_edit:
                listener.onEditContact(contactUri);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_delete:
                deleteContact();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void deleteContact() {

        confirmDelete.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "confirm delete");
    }

    // DialogFragment to confirm deletion of contact
   private final DialogFragment confirmDelete =
            new DialogFragment() {

                @Override
                public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle bundle) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                    builder.setTitle(R.string.confirm_title);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.confirm_message);


                    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_delete,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(
                                        DialogInterface dialog, int button) {


                                    getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(
                                            contactUri, null, null);
                                    listener.onContactDeleted();
                                }
                            }
                    );

                    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_cancel, null);
                    return builder.create();
                }
            };


    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        CursorLoader cursorLoader;

        switch (id) {
            case CONTACT_LOADER:
                cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                        contactUri,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);
                break;
            default:
                cursorLoader = null;
                break;
        }

        return cursorLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

        if (data != null && data.moveToFirst()) {

            int nameIndex = data.getColumnIndex(Contact.COLUMN_NAME);
            int emailIndex = data.getColumnIndex(Contact.COLUMN_EMAIL);


            nameTextView.setText(data.getString(nameIndex));
            emailTextView.setText(data.getString(emailIndex));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) { }
}
```

Ошибка находится здесь:

```
// DialogFragment to confirm deletion of contact
   private final DialogFragment confirmDelete =
            new DialogFragment() {

                @Override
                public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle bundle) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                    builder.setTitle(R.string.confirm_title);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.confirm_message);


                    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_delete,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(
                                        DialogInterface dialog, int button) {


                                    getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(
                                            contactUri, null, null);
                                    listener.onContactDeleted();
                                }
                            }
                    );

                    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_cancel, null);
                    return builder.create();
                }
            };
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41260696/7302343

Answer (score 0):

В ошибке сказано, что фрагмент должен быть статическим классом, а не анонимным. Попробуйте так и сделать:

```
private final DialogFragment confirmDelete = new MyDialogFragment();

static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle bundle) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setTitle(R.string.confirm_title);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.confirm_message);


        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_delete,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(
                            DialogInterface dialog, int button) {


                        getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(
                                contactUri, null, null);
                        listener.onContactDeleted();
                    }
                }
        );

        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_cancel, null);
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Подсвечивает contactUri и listener. Ошибка Non-static field 'contactUri' cannot be referenced from a static contex

Comment: Надо по другому эти вещи в статическом классе получать. `contactUri`, наверное, через `Bundle` в диалог передать, а `listener`, если он в активити реализован - получить кастованием активити. Ну или ещё как-то. Ибо да, члены внешнего класса не будут видны в статическом классе.